# Angular single-spa lazy loaded routes in lazy loaded modules give call of undefined webpack error

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, micro-frontend

I use single-spa with angular. I have a shell and a sub application, when my subapplication has lazy loaded modules so RootModule which loads SubModule Which loads SuperSubModule. All of these routes are lazy loaded routes. This works fine when i serve my application without single-spa and the single-spa webpack config. But when I build my application in production mode and aot, the lazy loaded route SubModule to SuperSubModule gives an error when i navigate to that url. The error is:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'call' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of
>   undefined
>       at o (bootstrap:63)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:396)
>       at Object.onInvoke (main.js:1)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:395)
>       at Object.onInvoke (core.js:39699)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:395)
>       at Zone.run (zone.js:153)
>       at zone.js:894
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:431)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (main.js:1)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:836)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:795)
>       at zone.js:897
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:431)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (main.js:1)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:430)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:430)
>       at Zone.runTask (zone.js:198)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:611)

When i click the url to that module again the error is:
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'undefined'.

> Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'undefined'.
>       at lg.resolve (compiler.js:20900)
>       at Th.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:20029)
>       at Jg._loadModules (compiler.js:25824)
>       at Jg._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:25807)
>       at Jg.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:25769)
>       at useClass.compileModuleAsync (platform-browser-dynamic.js:223)
>       at c.project (router.js:6406)
>       at c._tryNext (mergeMap.js:46)
>       at c._next (mergeMap.js:36)
>       at c.next (Subscriber.js:50)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:836)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:795)
>       at zone.js:897
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:431)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (main.js:1)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:430)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:430)
>       at Zone.runTask (zone.js:198)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:611)

Does anybody have any idea how to fix this? Any feedback is welcome, I have been stuck at this problem for days now.
Thanks in advance!
Edit: This only happens in production mode and when single-spa is used, not when served standalone in production mode.

Comment: I have the same issue.

Comment: Solution for me was found at: https://single-spa.js.org/docs/faq/#code-splits 
You have to do solution 1 and 2 to make it work, in our case 2 was forgotten. @Hack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is in FAQ from single-spa: 
https://single-spa.js.org/docs/faq/#code-splits
You have to do solution 1 and 2 to make it work, in our case 2 missed.